# How to include credentials when making CORS requests from Blazor?

Tags: asp.net-core, cors, blazor

On a blazor client application, what is the equivalent of jQuery ajax `WithCredentials` or JavaScript `credentials: 'include'`?

With Javascript I am able to say:

```
fetch('https://www.example.com/api/test', {
   credentials: 'include'
});
```

which includes auth cookie while making request and server responds with 200. I am trying to write same with Blazor using `HttpClient`.

Comment: read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: looks like constructing the `HttpRequestMessage` manually is the only option? I plan to use `AutoRest` generated REST client once I got the basic scenario verified though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Startup.Configure method you can set the WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler.DefaultCredentials to the required value of the 'credentials' option on outbound HTTP requests like this:

```
public void Configure(IComponentsApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Create("WEBASSEMBLY")))
            {

                WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler.DefaultCredentials = FetchCredentialsOption.Include;
            }

            app.AddComponent<App>("app");
        }
```

References:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c39fbb8f12002f61df6c093b0c11e6bd585ee202/src/Components/Blazor/Blazor/src/Http/WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler.cs

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/5a70f5312fb57fc3788e5af56a99e7b43761e195/src/Components/Blazor/Blazor/src/Http/FetchCredentialsOption.cs

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/d18a033b1ee6d923a72d440718c5d496b57c2ffc/src/Components/test/testassets/BasicTestApp/Startup.cs

Hope this helps...

Comment: Whoha! Just works! Not so sure if this is the recommended way though. I will have to check

Comment: I'm not sure, either...:). But this is the very code used by the Blazor team.

Comment: This seems to be not working in Preview3 but a fix for Preview4:https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/17115

Answer (score 7):

You can no longer set  `WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler.DefaultCredentials = FetchCredentialsOption.Include;` in your Startup file to achieve js`s `credentials: 'include'`

To achieve this in newer versions of blazor, you need to create a class that derives from `DelegatingHandler`, override `SendAsync` method and set `BrowserRequestCredentials` for `request` to `BrowserRequestCredentials.Include`

```cs
public class CookieHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public CookieHandler()
    {
        InnerHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.SetBrowserRequestCredentials(BrowserRequestCredentials.Include);

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

After it pass your `CookieHandler` to `HttpClient`

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient(new CookieHandler()) { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
```